# Composite video color resolution

Tags: composite-video

I have a rather theoretical question.

I connected my Raspberry Pi to my Composite NTSC TV and observed that the terminal video output has 640 pixels horizontal resolution with nice solid clear colors for text characters and logo. However, NTSC composite can only reliable produce less than 190 horizontal pixels without introducing color blurs and artifact colors (see [Composite artifact colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_artifact_colors)) because of the 3.58 MHz color carrier frequency used to decode color from composite signal.

I am puzzled how they can do this. Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: That is a fantastic question. Really it is very interesting but I doubt we have any visual experts on the exchange... it may even be more about electronics... possibly search the electronics stack exchange or photography stack exchange for similar questions. Seems like those bunch would know a heck lot more about NTSC and all the joys associated with it.

Comment: The luminance uses the full bandwidth. The chromanance signal which carries colour information is modulated on the color carrier, and as a consequence only has ~1.5MHz bandwidth. Any good book on colour TV will explain in more detail. This isn't a Pi question.

Comment: Did you read the question? This is exactly why I am asking it here - how Raspberry Pi managed to achieve 10 MHz resolution with 1.5 MHz bandwidth.

Comment: But this is NOT the question you actually asked. Computers can easily generate 10MHz monochrome, although this would not fit in a standard broadcast channel. This is how you can get 640 pixels; you cannot however get 10MHz colour, nor do you need it to get coloured text or logos, which only need 1.25MHz bandwidth. (You do NOT change colour on each pixel.)  This still isn't a Pi question.

Comment: Look, if you boot Pi, you will get colored terminal output and green/red Pi logo on the top of the screen. The text is 80 chars wide, each char is 8 pix. wide (I think) -  so you have 640 COLORED pixels on each line that may have several colors (green, blue, white) - therefore, for each character they MUST change color of each pixel with 10MHz frequency and still do not have the color smear. See this image (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_artifact_colors#/media/File:CGA_CompVsRGB_Text.png) to get an idea of how this was supposed to look like, but instead I see sharp solid colors.

Comment: I disagree. It's a question about how the Raspberry Pi works at a fundamental level. While I have no idea how composite video works, I'm voting to leave it open.

Comment: For those who interested - I have added this question to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274573/raspberry-pi-composite-color-video-resolution-puzzle